# Ext JS 4 Scatter plot - radius from data store

Tags: javascript, extjs4, scatter-plot

In Ext JS, I'm trying to make a Scatter chart. I want the radius of one of my scatter point to come from my store

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width : 800,
    height : 600,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [chart]
}).show();
});


var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
data: [
    { 'name': 'metric one',   'data1': 10, 'data2': 12, 'data3': 14, 'data4': 8,  'data5': 13 },
    { 'name': 'metric two',   'data1': 7,  'data2': 8,  'data3': 16, 'data4': 10, 'data5': 3  },
    { 'name': 'metric three', 'data1': 5,  'data2': 2,  'data3': 14, 'data4': 12, 'data5': 7  },
    { 'name': 'metric four',  'data1': 2,  'data2': 14, 'data3': 6,  'data4': 1,  'data5': 23 },
    { 'name': 'metric five',  'data1': 27, 'data2': 38, 'data3': 36, 'data4': 13, 'data5': 33 }
]
});


var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 500,
height: 300,
animate: true,
theme:'Category2',
store: store,
axes: [{
    type: 'Numeric',
    position: 'left',
    fields: ['data2', 'data3', 'data4'],
    title: 'Sample Values',
    grid: true,
    minimum: 0
}, {
    type: 'Category',
    position: 'bottom',
    fields: ['name'],
    title: 'Sample Metrics'
}],
series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    markerConfig: {
        type: 'circle',
        radius: 'data4' //This doesn't work!
    },
    axis: 'left',
    xField: 'name',
    yField: 'data2'
}, {
    type: 'scatter',
    markerConfig: {
        radius: 5,
        size: 5
    },
    axis: 'left',
    xField: 'name',
    yField: 'data3'
}]
});
```

Ok, so the problem line is commented with "//This doesn't work!". I understand why it doesn't work - Ext JS doesn't understand I'm trying to tell it to use the value from field data4.

So my question is, how do I get it to understand I want the radius to come from data4?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `renderer` function for `series` as below. It shows how to set color of individual points as well;

```
series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    //....
    renderer: function (sprite, record, attributes, index, store) {
                    var r = record.get('data4');
                    //var color = record.get('data5');
                    return Ext.apply(attributes, {
                        radius: r,
                        size: r
                      //  fill: color,
                    });
                }
}]
```

Comment: I have a question about this, there is more properties to change top-left radius only?.

Comment: @liss.sb as I remember these attributes are for svg circles. I suggest you copy Ext.chart.series.Scatter source code and modify to suit your requirement.